# Java: Mystery Invalid Method Reference

Tags: java, method-reference

With both JDK 1.8.0_181 and JDK 10.0.2 I receive this compilation error:

> test\Account.java:[13,88] error: incompatible types: invalid method reference

For this variable declaration:

`public final MetaProperty<Integer> BALANCE_PROP_INVALID = new MetaProperty<Integer>(Account::getBalance);`

But this one both compiles and runs just fine:

`public final MetaProperty<Integer> BALANCE_PROP_VALID = new MetaProperty<>(account -> ((Account) account).getBalance());`

[Here](https://gist.github.com/jasonCodesAway/183a21d1b299e702e701302d8db70b7f) is the gist. Does anyone know why that's invalid and hopefully a workaround?

FYI I am not interested in reflection.

Comment: I don't access to a computer at the moment so can't check, but I think `public MetaProperty(Function<? extends MetaObject, MetaProperty<P>> propertyGetter)` should fix it

Comment: @khachik I tried that, and a few other variations with the ? operator, but got the same result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your constructor expects a `Function<Object, T>` or similar. It has no way of knowing you intended an Account.  One way around this is to make the class have two generics.

```
class MetaProperty<A, R> {
    MetaProperty(Function<A, R> getter) { /* */ }
}

 public static final MetaProperty<Account, Integer> BALANCE_PROP_INVALID 
                                                    = new MetaProperty<>(Account::getBalance);
```

Comment: You are good!!! That did it. I thought specifying MetaObject in the ctor would've done it, since Account extends MetaObject, but no dice obviously. Thank you Peter!

Comment: @Jason that works if account is MetaObject, but not a sub class.